# Renderscript: Create a vector of structs

Tags: android, renderscript

I'm writing a small piece of Renderscript to dynamically take an image and sort the pixels into 'buckets' based on each pixel's RGB values.  The number of buckets could vary, so my instinct would be to create an arraylist.  This isn't possible within Renderscript, obviously, so I was wondering what the approach to creating a dynamic list of structs within the script. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please enhance your question by adding more details about the algorithm you are implementing. For some algorithms where the list size can be upper-bounded, you can simply allocate a array (Renderscript `Allocation` or `rs_allocation`) with the maximum possible size, if the upper-bound size is reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no clear answer to this. The problem is that dynamic memory management is anathema to platforms like RenderScript--it's slow, implies a lot of things about page tables and TLBs that may not be easy to guarantee from a given processor at an arbitrary time, and is almost never an efficient way to do what you want to do.

What the right alternative is depends entirely on what you're doing with the buckets after they're created. Do you need everything categorized without sorting everything into buckets? Just create a per-pixel mask (or use the alpha channel) and store the category alongside the pixel data. Do you have some upper bound on the size of each bucket? Allocate every bucket to be that size.

Sorry that this is open-ended, but memory management is one of those things that brings high-performance code to a screeching halt. Workarounds are necessary, but the right workaround varies in every case.

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for taking the time to answer. I understand - going from the wonderful, memory-managed world of Java to Renderscript is... a challenge. Essentially I'm writing an implementation of an algorithm to find the dominant colours of an image. Each colour is examined, compared to previous pixels using a Euclidean distance, and put into a bucket if the distance warrants it. Each bucket therefor contains simply the colour of the first pixel to initialise it and the number of pixels that've been allocated to it. Any further thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Further to this, would you recommend any specific resources to get a handle on this? I've checked out your I/O talk, but finding decent documentation/a reference book for this seems to be nigh impossible.

Comment: you could use atomics (atomic inc, whichever is first for a given bucket writes the initial pixel value), but that will be slow because of massive atomic contention. you could clip the launch to just the first column (Script.LaunchOptions), walk each row and put each row into its own set of buckets, and then combine those buckets in an invoke.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer your goal question of classifying pixel values, and *not your title question of creating a dynamically-sized list of structs*.

---

Without knowing much about your algorithm, I will frame my answer using one of the two algorithms:

1. RGB Joint Histogram

   - Does not use neighboring pixel values.
2. Connected Component

   - Requires neighboring pixel values.
   - Requires a supporting data structure called ["Disjoint set"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

---

#### Common advice.

Both algorithms require a lot of memory per worker thread. Also, both algorithms are poorly adapted to GPU because they require some kind of random memory access <sup>(Note)</sup>. Therefore, it is likely that both algorithms will end up being executed on the CPU. It is therefore a good idea to reduce the number of "threads" to avoid multiplying the memory requirement.

Note: Non-coalesced (non-sequential) memory access - reads, writes, or both.

---

#### RGB Joint Histogram

The best way is to compute a joint color histogram using Renderscript, and then run your classification algorithm on the histogram instead (presumably on the CPU). After that, you can perform a final step of pixel-wise label assignment back in Renderscript.

The whole process is almost exactly the same as Tim Murray's Renderscript presentation in Google I/O 2013.

- [Link to recorded session (video)](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/331954522)
- [Link to slides (PDF)](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/io-2013/presentations/151%20-%20RS%20IO%202013.pdf)

The joint color histogram will have to have hard-coded size. For example, a 32x32x32 RGB joint histogram uses 32768 histogram bins. This allows 32 levels of shades for each channel. The error per channel would be +/- 2 levels out of 256 levels.

---

#### Connected Component

I have successfully implemented multi-threaded connected component labeling on Renderscript. Note that my implementation is limited to execution on CPU; it is not possible to execute my implementation on the GPU.

**Prerequisites.**

- Understand the Union-Find algorithm (and its various theoretical parts, such as path-compression and ranking) and how connected-component labeling benefits from it.

**Some design choices.**

1. I use a 32-bit integer array, same size as the image, to store the "links".
2. Linking occurs in the same way as Union-Find, except that I do not have the benefit of ranking. This means the tree may become highly unbalanced, and therefore the path length may become long.
3. On the other hand, I perform path-compression at various steps of the algorithm, which counteracts the risk of suboptimal tree merging by shortening the paths (depths).

**One small but important implementation detail.**

1. The values stored in the integer array is essentially an encoding of the "(x, y)" coordinates to (i) itself, if the pixel is its own root, or (ii) a different pixel which has the same label as the current pixel.

**Steps.**

- The multi-threaded stage.

  - Divide the image into small tiles.
  - Inside each tile, compute the connected components, using label values local to that tile.
  - Perform path compression inside each tile.
  - Convert the label values into global coordinates and copy the tile's labels into the main result matrix.
- The single-threaded stage.

  - Horizontal stitching.
  - Vertical stitching.
  - A global round of path-compression.